# How to get date ranges from an array of static dates in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to create date ranges from statics dates of array.
Here is an example of what I want:

```
var collDates = [
  "2017/01/01", 
  "2017/01/02", 
  "2017/01/03", 
  "2017/01/04", 
  "2017/01/08", 
  "2017/01/09"
];
```

This should be transformed to:

```
[
  { start_date: "2017/01/01", end_date: "2017/01/04" }, 
  { start_date: "2017/01/08", end_date: "2017/01/09" }
];
```

Comment: Why don't you first show what you have tried so far? and what was the problem in that?

Comment: so you want logic?

Comment: OP - please try something first, use your noggin. @SaurabhAgrawal yes, this seems to be the case.

Comment: Please @SaurabhAgrawal  see the answer. I have resolved it.

Comment: I was going to do the same @PrabhdeepSingh

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue and here is an example code.

```
var staticDates = ["2017/01/01", "2017/01/02", "2017/01/03", "2017/01/04", "2017/01/08", "2017/01/09", "2017/01/10", "2017/01/11", "2017/01/12", "2017/01/13", "2017/01/14", "2017/01/15", "2017/01/16", "2017/01/17", "2017/01/18", "2017/01/19", "2017/01/20", "2017/01/21", "2017/01/22", "2017/01/23", "2017/01/24", "2017/01/25", "2017/01/26", "2017/01/27", "2017/01/28", "2017/01/29"];
var coll_dateIntervals = []; 
var arr_temp = []; 
var i = 1;
$.each(staticDates, function(index, moment_date){ 

//Day difference in # of days 
 var diff = Math.abs(moment(staticDates[index]).diff(staticDates[index + 1], "days")); 

   arr_temp.push(moment_date); 

  //Check the date difference in days. 
  if(diff <= 1 && diff !== undefined){ 

   //If the difference is 1, than add the date to the temporary array 
   arr_temp.push(moment_date); 

  //If it's more than 1 day, or the last object 
 } else if (diff > 1 || diff === undefined){ 
   //Store the interval in an object 
   console.log(arr_temp[arr_temp.length - 1]);
   var obj_dateInterval = { start_date: moment(arr_temp[0],  "YYYY/MM/DD").format('YYYY-MM-DD'), end_date:    moment(arr_temp[arr_temp.length - 1], "YYYY/MM/DD").format('YYYY-MM-DD')}; 
   coll_dateIntervals.push(obj_dateInterval); 

   //Empty the array to start the new loop 
   arr_temp = [];  

 }

}); 
console.log(coll_dateIntervals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a library, you just need a couple of simple functions for parsing and formatting. Doesn't do anything with invalid dates, but not difficult to add if required.

Step through the dates to create ranges. Begin with a start date, calculate the next day as current date plus one. When get a date that isn't the next day, end the range and start a new one. Also end when run out of dates.

For single dates, creates a single date range.

```js
/* Parse date in format y/m/d
 ** @param {string} s - string to parse
 ** @returns {Date}
 */
function parseYMD(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2])
}

/* Collate array of date strings in y/m/d format to ranges
** @param {Array} dateArray - array of dates to parse in y/m/d format
** @returns {Array} ranges in format {start_date: yyyy/mm/dd, end_date: yyyy/mm/dd}
*/
function datesToRanges(dateArray) {

  return dateArray.reduce(function(acc, currentDate, index) {
    var d = parseYMD(currentDate);

    // Start of a processing, initialise accumulator
    if (!acc) {
      acc = {range: {start_date: currentDate}, ranges: []};

      // If not continuing range, end current range, store and start new  
    } else if (acc.previousDate.setDate(acc.previousDate.getDate() + 1) != +d) {
      acc.range.end_date = acc.previousString;
      acc.ranges.push(acc.range);
      acc.range = {start_date: currentDate};
    }

    // Keep current values for next iteration
    acc.previousDate = d;
    acc.previousString = currentDate;

    // If at end of dates, end current range
    if (index == dateArray.length - 1) {
      acc.range.end_date = currentDate;
      acc.ranges.push(acc.range);
    }

    return acc;
  }, null).ranges;
}

// Tests
var collDates = [
  "2017/01/01", // Start 4 day range
  "2017/01/02",
  "2017/01/03",
  "2017/01/04", // End 4 day range
  "2017/01/06", // Zero day range
  "2017/01/08", // Start one day range
  "2017/01/09", // End one day range
  "2017/01/15", // Zero day range
];

console.log(datesToRanges(collDates));
```

PS

Can't see what this has to do with jQuery. There's no moment.js tag so I haven't used it. ;-)